# How to add functionality to a UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, function, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

So I've created two functions (nenuProgressButton & nenuSurvivalButton)
I'm wanting nenuProgressButton to provide 0.1 to a progress bar when clicked, and nenuSurvival to add 0.5 when selecting the action title on the UIalert. I can get most of this to work fine, but when I Select "Apply" which is the title of the uialert action,  it adds 0.1 to my progress bar, and then if I click it again the progress bar pretty much freezes. or if I initially click uialert action title it will add 0.1, but then if I click on the nenuProgress button, it will add 0.5 rather then 0.1, and if I click the progress button again, the progress bar will minus the 0.5, can go back to its previous state. I'm very unsure what's causing this complication, but here is my code and would appreciate any help massively, thanks

```
class Characters: UIViewController {
    
    var pb = ProgressBrain()
    var toNextLevel = 10
    var xpGained = 1
    var nenuEx = 1
    var nenuSurvival = 5
    
    @IBOutlet var nenuProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var remfoProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var oneiroProgress: UIProgressView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet var nenuLevel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var nenuTab: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var selector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var characterImg: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var routine: UIView!
    var views: [UIView]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func progressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        nenuProgressButton()
    }
    
    
    func nenuProgressButton() {
        
        
        let percentageProgress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        
        if xpGained < toNextLevel + 1{
            
            
            nenuProgress.progress = Float(percentageProgress)
            print(Float(percentageProgress))
            
            xpGained += 1
            
        } else if xpGained == toNextLevel + 1 {
            
            
            nenuProgress.progress = 0.0
            xpGained -= toNextLevel
            switch nenuLevel.text {
            case "1":
                nenuProgress.progress = 0.0
                
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "2"
                
            case "2":
                
                xpGained = 1
                
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "3"
            case "3":
                
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "4"
            case "4":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "5"
            case "5":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "6"
            case "6":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "7"
            case "7":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "8"
            case "8":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "9"
            case "9":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "10"
            default:
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
            
        }
    }
    func nenuSurvivalButton() {
        
        
        let percentageProgress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        
        nenuProgress.progress = Float(percentageProgress)
        print(Float(percentageProgress))
        
        
        nenuProgress.progress += Float(xpGained)
        
        xpGained += 5

        if xpGained >= toNextLevel + 1 {
            
            
            nenuProgress.progress = 0.0
            xpGained -= toNextLevel
            switch nenuLevel.text {
            case "1":
                nenuProgress.progress = 0.0
                
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "2"
                
            case "2":
                
                xpGained = 5
                
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "3"
            case "3":
                
                
                xpGained = 5
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "4"
            case "4":
                
                xpGained = 5
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "5"
            case "5":
                
                xpGained = 5
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "6"
            case "6":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "7"
            case "7":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "8"
            case "8":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "9"
            case "9":
                
                xpGained = 1
                toNextLevel += 3
                nenuLevel.text = "10"
            default:
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func nenuPopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Perform Application", message: "48 Laws of power", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apply", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.nenuSurvivalButton()
    } ))
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `ProgressBrain`?

Comment: Currently it's pretty empty 
class ProgressBrain: UIViewController {
  
 
    var level = 0
    var toNextLevel = 1
    var xpGained = 0.1
    
   
   
}